# Changing a String Formation in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i have strings like

"2014-06-01 - Today"
or
"2014-05-01 - 2014-06-01"

in both cases i would wish the date part is formated like
"01-06-2014 - Today"
or
"01-05-2014 - 01-06-2014"

finally just turning from back to front the date

Im not as good in that formating with gsub.. or any other expression way.

Comment: gsub can probably do your job. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an idea:

```
local v1 = "2014-06-01 - Today"
local v2 = "01-06-2014 - Today"

assert(v1:gsub('(%d%d%d%d)%-(%d%d)%-(%d%d)', "%3-%2-%1") == v2)
```

Patterns: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1
Tutorial: http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial

So, you can somehow(use smth like `match`) distinguish between your variants and then use corresponding pattern.

EDIT: as @lhf pointed out, I miss escaping of `-` sign in pattern in my first example. Also he noticed, that in your case, gsub can automatically make substitution twice, so following code should be correct:

```
local v1 = "2014-06-01 - Today"
local v2 = "01-06-2014 - Today"
local v3 = "2014-05-01 - 2014-06-01"
local v4 = "01-05-2014 - 01-06-2014"

local convert = function(str)
    return str:gsub('(%d%d%d%d)%-(%d%d)%-(%d%d)', "%3-%2-%1")
end

assert(convert(v1) == v2)
assert(convert(v3) == v4)
```

Comment: You probably need to escape `-` with `%-`.

Comment: There is no need to distinguish between variants; `gsub` does a global change.

Comment: @lhf Thank you, my bad. I should not answer on the edge of sleep ;) Edited, mentioning you as idea author. Hope you don't mind.